# Find identity element, invertible and inverses in $T=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Q$

Tags: semigroups

Let the following operation be defined on $T=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Q$:

$$\begin{aligned}(a,b)\centerdot (c,d) = (-ac, b+d+2) \end{aligned}$$

in the commutative semigroup $(T, \centerdot)$, find the identity element, invertible elements and inverses.

I need to find the identity element, so I need an $(\alpha, \beta)$ so that

$$\begin{aligned}(a,b)\centerdot (\alpha,\beta) = (a,b) \end{aligned}$$

as $(T, \centerdot)$ is a commutative semigroup, I assume that $(\alpha,\beta)\centerdot (a,b) = (a,b)$ holds.

$$\begin{aligned}-a\alpha = a \Leftrightarrow \alpha = -1 \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}b+\beta+2 = b \Leftrightarrow \beta = -2 \end{aligned}$$

so the identity element relative to this semigroup is $(-1,-2)$.

In order to find the invertible elements and inverses:

$$\begin{aligned}(a,b)\centerdot (a',b') = (-1,-2) \end{aligned}$$

so

$$\begin{aligned}-aa' = -1 \Leftrightarrow a'=-\frac{1}{a} \in \mathbb Z \Rightarrow a = 1 \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}b+b'+2=-2 \Leftrightarrow b'=-(b+4) \end{aligned}$$

in conclusion only the elements $(1,b)$ are actually invertible and their inverse is $(1, -(b+4))$.

Does this whole thing hold? Am I wrong in any part of it?

Comment: In the last bit, why can't $a$ be $-1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson because I need $(-aa') = -1$ if $a = -1$ then $(-aa') = 1$.

Comment: As @GerryMyerson pointed out $a$ cab be $-1\implies a'=-1\implies $ inverse of $(-1,b)$ also exists and is equal to $(-1,-(b+4)).$

Comment: After equation $-aa'=-1$ $a'=\frac{-1}{a}$ is wrong, it should be $\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: @avatar thank you I've really overlooked that minus sign!! what a shame!

Comment: You keep asking questions about this kind of problem. Are you actually managing to solve some of them on your own, or are you having difficulties with all of them?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, right now most of them seem to be quite scary! I am getting acquainted with the subject, this isn't exactly my field, but I gotta master it for a test I have to take... so I sure feel I need a bit of help to solve this kind of exercises and try to get as many feedbacks as possible to get ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of these problems, you are taking a structure with operations that you "already know", and are trying to test to see whether a *new* operation, defined in terms of the ones you know, satisfies certain properties.

It's usually best to denote the "new" operation with a symbol that is unlikely to generate confusion. You've been doing this elsewhere, but here you are using $\cdot$, which can easily be confused with regular integer multiplication. So I'm going to replace it with $\odot$, if you don't mind.

Let's approach it systematically, and essentially "following your nose." I'm going to check a few things that you seem to take for granted, just to get familiarity with the operation.

Now, we have the set $T=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Q}$, and the operation
$$(a,b)\odot (c,d) = (-ac, b+d+2).$$
First, the operation is commutative, since integer multiplication and addition of rationals is commutative. It is also associative:
$$\begin{align*}
\Bigl( (a,b)\odot (c,d)\Bigr)\odot (x,y) &= (-ac, b+d+2)\odot (x,y)\\
&=(-(-ac)x,(b+d+2)+y+2)\\
&= (acx, b+d+y+4)\\
(a,b)\odot \Bigl((c,d)\odot (x,y)\Bigr)&= (a,b)\odot (-cx, d+y+2)\\
&= (-a(-cx), b+(d+y+2)+2)\\
&= (acx, b+d+y+4).
\end{align*}$$
So the operation is commutative and associative, and we do indeed have a semigroup.

Now we are trying to see whether this is a monoid (semigroup with identity). So we are trying to see whether there exist $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that, for **all** $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have
$$(\alpha,\beta)\odot(a,b) = (a,b)$$
(exactly as you did). This amounts to solving the equations you solved, which you did correctly, and so we discovered that $(T,\odot)$ is *indeed* a monoid, and that the identity element is $e_T = (-1,-2)$. Great!

To figure out what elements have inverses, you do set $(a,b)\odot (x,y) =e_T = (-1,-2)$, and figure out if you can determine necessary and sufficient conditions on $a$ and $b$ for $x$ and $y$ to exist. As you note, we have:
$$(-1,-2) = (a,b)\odot(x,y) = (-ax, b+y+2).$$
This requires $-ax = 1$, which means that $a$ has to be an integer that has a multiplicative inverse in the integers (namely, $-x$); there are only two possibilities: $a=1$ or $a=-1$.

On the other hand, for *any* rational number $b$ we can always find a rational number $y$ such that $b+y+2=-2$, namely, as you note, $y = -(b+4)$. So it would seem that provided that $a=\pm 1$, then $(a,b)$ has an $\odot$-inverse in $T$. And, indeed, if $a=\pm 1$, then we have $$(\pm 1,b)\odot (\pm1,-b-4) = (-(\pm1)(\pm 1), b-b-4+2) = (-1-2).$$
So a necessary and sufficient condition for $(a,b)\in T$ to be $\odot$-invertible is that $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: thank you so much for your patient, clear and most of all exhaustive answer, appreciated.